# How to increment a xpath and save it in a variable - selenium IDE

Tags: xpath, selenium-ide

I'd like to increment the xpath in a loop by increment the count in a variable, please check the code below:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeXpathCount</td>
    <td>xpath=.//*[@id='vicinityListDropDown']/span</td>
    <td>nsuvcount</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>getEval</td>
    <td>storedVars['nsuvcount']=${nsuvcount}+1</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Actually this code is in a loop where will wait for this xpath (storeElementPath) and take a screenshot, However I'd like to count each time this xpath will be displayed in the loop, so I'd like to save the total (times) in a variable, i.e(nsuvcount=10), that means the xpath was found 10 times, This is an error message.

I appreciate your help!